# Adding time of order to Admin email for new order

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, email

I have set plain text for new orders from woocommerce shop, they are getting printed, fine. But it is important to know the time when the user placed the order. The time is not mentioned on the printed slip. Following is the text/code inside the plain email template.

```
 do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );
```

Can you please advise what i should add in this to get time of order printed?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

paste this below code your active theme functions.php  file

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'order_date_email_hook', 10, 4);

function order_date_email_hook( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){
    if ( $sent_to_admin ) 
    {
        echo '<span>Order Date: '.$order->get_date_created().'</span>';
      }
}
```